# How does one perform a blocking read from the UART of an Azure Sphere?

Tags: blocking, uart, azure-sphere

I'm using the read method from the "unistd.h" header with a sleep of 1 second to read data from Azure Sphere's UART pins. Is there a built-in method of performing a blocking reading of UART data on the Azure Sphere?

Comment: Word order improved, terminogy used was inconsistant and weird.

Comment: Can you detail better what you are trying to achieve and are you using the UART Sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-development/uart-sample)?